# Issues with Realtek Wifi Card

Tags: wifi, networking, drivers, internet

I installed elementary OS 7 on my laptop 2 days ago. In the beginning everything was working well, but today my Wifi simply stopped working. I can see no available connections in the network list and although I'm able to connect to the internet through a wired connection, I cannot create a hotspot on my computer. I'm not shown any error when I turn the hotspot on, but it doesn't show up as an available connection to other devices in the vicinity. Running `dmesg` shows the following error messages which I believe are related:

```
[  107.750470] rtw_8822be 0000:07:00.0: failed to read ASPM, ret=-5
[  109.749418] rtw_8822be 0000:07:00.0: failed to poll offset=0x5 mask=0x2 value=0x0
[  109.749434] rtw_8822be 0000:07:00.0: mac power on failed
[  109.749436] rtw_8822be 0000:07:00.0: failed to power on mac
[  109.749438] rtw_8822be 0000:07:00.0: leave idle state failed
[  109.749624] rtw_8822be 0000:07:00.0: failed to leave ips state
```

Running `lspci` reveals this to be my wifi card: `Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8822BE 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WiFi adapter`

Any help on solving this issue is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

*Update: After following Vlad's suggestions, some of the error messages disappeared, namely the ones related to ASPM, but I see the following new ones now:*

```
[    6.568678] rtw_8822be 0000:07:00.0: Unable to change power state from D3cold to D0, device inaccessible
[    6.575083] rtw_8822be 0000:07:00.0: failed to setup chip efuse info
[    6.575114] rtw_8822be 0000:07:00.0: failed to setup chip information
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same adapter, and I had to install driver from https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw88 to make it work:

Install dependencies:
`sudo apt-get update`
`sudo apt-get install make gcc linux-headers-$(uname -r) build-essential git`

Clone the repo:
`git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw88.git`

Build and install driver:
`cd rtw88`
`make`
`sudo make install`
`sudo reboot`

I now have 99% consistent WiFi connection, even between resumes & restarts.

OBSERVATIONS:

1. You'll need to install the driver after every kernel update, so keep the cloned folder at hand.
   `cd ~/rtw88`
   `git pull`
   `make`
   `sudo make install`
2. Sometimes, after a restart, WiFi will be off, trying `sudo rfkill unblock all` might work, or turn off laptop, remove power supply, wait a minute or two, power on laptop. Inside the repo folder there's a suspend  script, might want to try it if you have serious issues with dead WiFi after suspend `sudo cp suspend_rtw8822be /usr/lib/systemd/system-sleep/`
3. You may also need to turn aspm off after installing the driver:
   `sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/r8822be.conf`
   inside this file paste `options r8822be aspm=0`
   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to save file
   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to close nano
   reboot

Comment: I tried this, and although it worked at first, rebooting broke it again. I tried rebooting multiple times, and found that although the wifi works sometimes it's not nearly as consistent as yours. Any further ideas?

Comment: You may also need to turn aspm off for the card. I added one extra step at my answer

Comment: I've now turned the aspm off as suggested. At the moment it seems to be working. Hopefully reboots won't break it like last time around

Comment: I hope it stays stable. If it fails, in my case, it happens about 1 minute after power up. From what i read, it's a power management issue with the realtek chips, and also sometimes the OS cannot read the 'state' of the chip at power up

Comment: Sadly the stability does not seem to have improved. Although it was working yesterday, it has died again today. A notable thing however is that the ASPM related error messages don't show anymore, but there are new error messages that weren't there previously. I've appended these to the original post.

Comment: Do you have powertop installed by any chance?

Comment: You may need to blacklist the prev driver, in my case it was needed when using elementary 6.1. As https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw88 says: create an `/etc/modprobe.d/rtw88_8822be.conf` file and put `blacklist rtw88_8822be` inside. Since elementary OS 7, I did not have to do this, but maybe it is needed for you.

Comment: I don't have powertop installed. I tried blacklisting the driver as you said, but it doesn't seem to work. Even after a reboot, `lsmod` still shows `rtw88_8822be` as a loaded module.

Comment: I think I may have mistaken the name for the file in the blacklist module. Please try to rename `rtw_8822be.conf` to `rtl8822be.conf`. The contents should still remain `blacklist rtw88_8822be`. You can also try to unload the wrong module `modprobe -r  rtw88_8822be` and load the correct one with `modprobe rtw_8822be`

Comment: I've made the changes and have also added the following line `options rtw_pci disable_aspm=Y` to the file `/etc/modprobe.d/r8822be.conf`. Although the wifi has failed to work on a few start ups, it seems to be working fairly consistently now. I suppose we can now consider the problem solved. Thanks a bunch for your help @Vlad.

Comment: Happy to help! As I said, this driver is not 100% foolproof, but it sure beats the old one. I am looking to replace the wireless adapter soon, so Untile then it gets the job done for me.